# ¿Es posible utilizar una variable que está dentro de un evento en un evento diferente en VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, variables

buen día.

Quisiera saber si alguien me puede orientar con esta duda que se me presentó. Espero ser claro con mi explicación y también puedan apoyarme un poco, soy muy nuevo en este lenguaje y me gustaría un poco de retroaliemtación. Gracias por darse el tiempo de revisar mi pregunta y por su apoyo!

Tal cómo se muestra en el título es lo que quiero conocer, pondré un ejemplo respecto a el código que estoy desarrollando actualmente.

En un evento ***x*** tengo una variable que me permite leer la dirección de la carpeta que acabo de seleccionar con ayuda de un `FolderBrowserDialog` y que se acaba de añadir a mi control TreeView como un *Nodo* (Carpeta destino).

La variable es la siguiente: `DirecciónProyecto = Path.GetDirectoryName(Proyecto.SelectedPath)`

La respuesta de esta variable es: C:\Users\Usuariox\Documents

Lo que se quiere hacer es añadir archivos de otra carpeta que se encuentra en otra dirección a ese *Nodo* y que se creen como *Subnodos*, entonces lo que hago es copiar el archivo que está en la otra carpeta y añadirlo a la carpeta destino (*Nodo*). Lo hago con el siguiente fragmento de código:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(DirecciónOrigen, DirecciónDestino & "\" & FileName)
```

Este último fragmento está en un evento ***y***, tengo una variable aquí que al seleccionar el *Nodo* que había añadido en el evento ***x*** me da la dirección en donde se encuentra esa carpeta, la variable es la siguiente:

```
Dim CarpetaDestino = TV.SelectedNode.Name
Dim DirecciónDestino = Path.GetFullPath(CarpetaDestino)
```

Aquí es donde está el problema y por lo que me gustaría usar la variable del evento ***x***, esta dirección me da como resultado la carpeta de debug en donde está desarrollándose el código de mi programa, a continuación presento lo que me arroja:

```
C:\Users\Usuariox\Careptax\Programa\NombrePrograma\bin\Debug\Nodo
```

En lugar de darme la dirección que esperaba: **C:\Users\Usuariox\Documents**, sin embargo sé que el error está en seleccionar directamente el Subnodo, porque este es el que lee el dato que no quiero y me gustaría tomar la variable del evento ***x*** para utilizarla en esta parte del evento ***y***.

Comment: depende de si la variable tiene un scope global y el orden en que ocurren los eventos ...

Comment: la respuesta es si se puede XD

Comment: Se pueden usar variables globales pero, en mi opinión, cuando es necesario usar una variable global es que hay algún fallo de diseño en la aplicación. Yo personalmente las evito siempre que puedo (y se puede prácticamente siempre).

Comment: @CarlosAdrián y Arcanis - The Omnipotent, gracias por sus comentarios, me ayudaron mucho, utilicé las variables globales cosa que quería llegar a evitar pero me ayudó mucho a solucionar el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza variables globales fuera de los eventos y actualiza-las cuando se produzcan los eventos

Asumiendo que en DirecciónOrigen Tienes la Dirección del Archivo a hacer CopYDirectory

```
Public RutaX As String = vbNullString
Public RutaY As String = vbNullString
Public DirProyect = Path.GetDirectoryName(Proyecto.SelectedPath)

Private Sub Evento_Y()
   ' Aquí DirecciónOrigen Se Asume Que Tiene una Ruta de Carpeta
   Dim DireccionOrigen As String = DirProyect ' Asigna-le el valor 
   Dim DireccionDestino As String = RutaY & "\" & My.Computer.FileSystem.GetName(RutaY)
   My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(DireccionOrigen, DireccionDestino)
End Sub

Private Sub Evento_X()
   On Error Resume Next

   Dim CarpetaDestino = TV.SelectedNode.Name
   Dim DireccionDestino = Path.GetFullPath(CarpetaDestino)

   RutaX = CarpetaDestino
   RutaY = DireccionDestino

End Sub
```